# iOS8.1 cannot receive apple push

Tags: ios, ios8, apple-push-notifications, push, ios8.1

Users receive a alert which ask them to receive apple push when they use our app first time. The OS Version of the device is ios 8.0 or later.User allow the request. ios8.0 device can receive apple push, but ios 8.1 can not. I use this code:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
 not use：
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

I do not know the error!Someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem ,the follow codes help me! In iOS 8,the way to register remote notification has been changed.

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                                                 settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                                                                 categories:nil]];


            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
        else
        {
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "show" instead of the "push" because the latter is deprecated, and it is a hint that it will not be use anymore in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this code for ios7 & ios 8 in `AppDelegate` in `appDidFinishLaunch`

```
/*--- Setup Push Notification ---*/
//For iOS 8
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)] && [UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
//For iOS 7 & less
else if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)])
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}
```

Maybe you don't need this but if you need than to receive Remote Notification Method

```
#pragma mark - For Remote Notification
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
//register to receive notifications
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
//handle the actions
//    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
//    }
//    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
//    }
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSString *device_Token = [[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {

 // show some alert or otherwise handle the failure to register.
 NSLog(@"error : %@",error.localizedDescription);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [self SetUpActionWhenPushNotiClicked:userInfo application:application PushPop:NO];
}
-(void)SetUpActionWhenPushNotiClicked:(NSDictionary*)userInfo application:(UIApplication *)application PushPop:(BOOL)pushpop
{
NSLog(@"UserInfo : %@",userInfo);
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
if (userInfo)
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
    {
        //NSLog(@"app is already open");
    }
    else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground ||
             application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        //NSLog(@"app is coming from bg");
    }
}

}
```

Maybe this will help you.